# Usage value of callback in simple example

Tags: javascript, function, callback

The following example demonstrate callback:

**Example 1:** - Using Callback

```
<script>
// The callback method
function meaningOfLife() {
    console.log("The meaning of life is: 42");
}

// A method which accepts a callback method as an argument
function printANumber(number, callback) {
    console.log("The number you provided is: " + number);
    callback();
}

// Driver method
printANumber(6, meaningOfLife);
</script>
```

Result:

```
The number you provided is: 6
The meaning of life is: 42
```

**Example 2:** - Normal function calling

```
<script>
// A simple function
function meaningOfLife() {
    console.log("The meaning of life is: 42");
}

// Another simple function
function printANumber(number) {
    console.log("The number you provided is: " + number);
    meaningOfLife();
}

// Call to second function
printANumber(6);
</script>
```

Result:

```
The number you provided is: 6
The meaning of life is: 42
```

> Now, when I can get my result simply by normal function calling, then what is the use case of Callback? Why so much fuss? Even by making a simple call to a method from inside another function I can achieve my task (Always). Why in world then huge fuss of callback is there? What special work has it done in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why in world then huge fuss of callback is there?

Because then it is the caller that decides what should be invoked next.

Comment: Care an example sir?

Comment: @Peterson your code are examples. In #1 the caller decides what to do next, in #2 the implementation does.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you need to calculate value after 10ms delay and then return it but you do not want the main thread waiting 10ms.
Then you can do something like this:

```js
function doSomeStuff(callback) {
   var i = 12;
   callback(i);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  doSomeStuff(function(i) {
     console.log(i);
  });  
}, 10);

// Do something else before "doSomeStuff" is called
```

Callbacks are usually used with asynchronous method calls in a single-threaded languages ​​(eg when loading resources via XMLHTTPRequest)

And, of course, you should read some info about closures in js